# Search data in multiple tables

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

Let’s say, I have 2 tables in Azure SQL – Employee & Address and both the tables have common field, say Address Id.

Question:

1. If I create separate indexes for tables, can I search the data in both indexes from single search API? Is it possible to join 2 indexes? Just cross checking if such functionality exists.
2. Another option I am aware of is – load data from both the tables to single index using solution given in below. Is this possible only via .NET API? Can we develop it from Portal?
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/tutorial-multiple-data-sources
3. Any other recommended approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I create separate indexes for tables, can I search the data in both
> indexes from single search API? Is it possible to join 2 indexes? Just
> cross checking if such functionality exists.

No. Search is only limited to a single index. You would need to combine the search results from multiple indexes on the client side.

> Another option I am aware of is – load data from both the tables to
> single index using solution given in below. Is this possible only via
> .NET API? Can we develop it from Portal?

You should be able to do it from the portal. Essentially the idea is to create two data sources (one for each table), two indexers (one for each data source) and have these indexers populate the data into a single index.

Another idea would be to create a database view that combines the data from these two tables and use that view as the data source for your index. That way you don't have to create separate data sources and indexers.

Answer (score 0):

just use this:

namespace WebApplication1.Data
{
public class allstudents
{
[Key]
public int Id { get; set; }

```
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
}
```

}